# PHP string to contain and output another PHP variable

Tags: php, variables

In my PHP application I am displaying embedded videos from various sources - youtube, vimeo etc.

In my articles table I store the id of my embed videos:

```
Article.video_url = 'e5dkjwkdek'
```

Then in my video_providers table I store the embed code, but I want to dynamically add the video_url, so I store:

```
VideoProviders.embedcode = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/$article->video_url"
```

I then output the 'embedcode' variable in my template and I want to append the $article->video_url which is the unique id of the video.

It seems I need a variable within the variable, I tried:

```
VideoProviders.embedcode = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$article->video_url}"
```

and

VideoProviders.embedcode = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/$$article->video_url"

But it seems these are simply treated as literal strings. If anyone has any better suggestions as to how to achieve this I am all ears. In short I want the mark-up stored in one place so that is can be edited should the embed code of the provider change.

Comment: Where does this code exist?  Why does it look like you're mixing js and php?

Comment: the left side is supposed to represent the table and its field, so "embedcode" is the field of the VideoProviders table

Comment: So you're storing a literal $article in your database and you want it evaluated when you echo that string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store strings with PHP interpolation symbols. Double-quoted strings are interpolated at runtime.

I'd say you have three options...

1. Store the various parts in your database and construct them in your query. For example (assuming MySQL)

   ```sql
   SELECT
     CONCAT(VideoProviders.embed_prefix, Article.video_url) AS embedcode,
     -- etc
   ```

   with `VideoProviders.embed_prefix` containing `'https://www.youtube.com/embed/'`, `'https://player.vimeo.com/video/'`, etc
2. Store the URL with placeholders for the video *id* and (again assuming MySQL) use the [`REPLACE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function. For example

   ```
   VideoProviders.embedcode = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/{VIDEO_ID}'
   ```

   and

   ```sql
   SELECT
     REPLACE(VideoProviders.embedcode, '{VIDEO_ID}', Article.video_url) AS embedcode,
     -- etc
   ```

   This would be the preferred solution if the video *id* doesn't always appear at the end of the URL.
3. Store a `printf` style pattern in `embedcode`, eg `'https://www.youtube.com/embed/%s'` and put it together with PHP, eg

   ```
   $embedcode = sprintf($row['embedcode'], $row['video_url');
   ```

Comment: the 3rd suggestion does exactly what I need - sprintf

Comment: That's sort of odd. It's really no different to option #2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just do this:

```
$video_id = 'e5dkjwkdek';
$provider_url = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';

$embed_code = $provider_url . $video_id;
```

Or something similar to this. You can fill the video_id and provider_url anyway you like. From a database or from some other source. This way should always work.

Comment: this would have worked but there are more parts to the mark-up which would have meant breaking the embed code up into the before and after sections which I think could get messy